# What's the space complexity?

Tags: python, space-complexity

I'm not sure what is the space complexity of the following function? Is it `O(n)` or `O(1)`?

```
# Do rotation
def foo(arr):
    arr[:] = arr[5:] + arr[:5]
```

Answer (score 3):

Each of `arr[5:]` and `arr[:5]` builds a new list, before joining into another new list that gets assigned to `arr` in-place. Both `arr[5:]` and the joined list require *O(n)* in space complexity, so the overall space complexity is *O(n)*.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the type of `arr`, but assuming it's a `list`, it's O(n), since both slices on the RHS create new `list` objects, albeit temporarily. Those two are concatenated into a *third* new list, whose elements are then copied into the existing list referenced by `arr`.

You can accomplish O(1) space complexity by using `itertool.slice` to avoid making copies:

```
def foo(arr):
    arr[:] = chain(islice(arr, 5, None), islice(arr, 5))
```